# Находясь в теге script узнать parentElement

Tags: javascript

Есть html

```
<body>
  <hi>test</hi>
  <script>
    var hi = this.parentElement.firstElementChild;
    alert(hi.data);
  </script>
<body>
```

Пример синтаксический, и работать конечно не будет, но мне нужно узнать из скрипта ноду в которой он находиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент обработки скрипта документ ещё парсится, поэтому можно запросить теги script и взять впоследний - он и будет текущим тегом. Только это надо делатьсразу, без использования асинхронных операций и без ожидания загрузки документа.

```
<div>The 1st div</div>
<script>
function getMyScript(callback) {
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
    callback(scripts[scripts.length-1]);
}
</script>
<div>The 2nd div</div>
<script>getMyScript(function(s){alert(s.textContent)})</script>
<div>The 3rd div</div>
<script>getMyScript(function(s){alert(s.previousElementSibling.outerHTML)})</script>
<div>The 4th div</div>
<script>alert("Yes!");</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bw60g6yt/ - открой ссылку, подтверди 3 alert'а, потом нажми run. Обрати внимание, как при отображении alert'ов меняется отображённая часть документа.